# asp.net core 2.0 load unminified script for specific view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, minify, asp.net-core-2.0

So I want to load a specific javascript file for one particular view. At the moment I implemented it like this (production code):

```
<script src=@Url.Content("js/someLibrary.min.js")></script>
```

But for my development environment I want to load the unminified version of this file. However when I leave this code as it is it will still pull the min.js file from the server.

Is there any way in which I can load the unminified version depending on my current environment for a specific view, without loading the file in every view (through _Layout.cshtml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the unminified file is called **js/someLibrary.js** this should do the trick:

```
<script src=@Url.Content("js/someLibrary.js")></script>
```

EDIT:

To be able to differentiate what to use when in dev mode and when in prod mode you can add a key to the appfile config and check its value.

```
<add key="DevMode" value="true" />
```

for your dev and

```
<add key="DevMode" value="false" />
```

for your prod. And then you can use

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DevMode")
```

to get its value.

Comment: I edited my question. I want the unminified version to load when i'm developing but the minified version to load when I'm not